# Injustice 2 will not start on Xbox One

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one, injustice-2

For some reason, Injustice 2 won't start.

I bought it on a disc and tried everything to fix it and make it start,  including:

- Reinstalling several times
- Restarted Xbox several times
- Cleared all unused data on the Xbox
- Starting the game with no DLC
- Deleting and then unplugging the Xbox for 30 seconds before plugging it bag in
- Turning off the whole Xbox and waited 3 hours.

But none of these worked. It crashes before it even reaches the start screen.

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be in issue on the developers side with the game as [this article](https://gamertweak.com/xbox-login-error-bc124-fix/) discusses:

> But unfortunately, none of it has worked. That’s because the problem is from the developer’s side so there is nothing you can do from your end. All we can do is wait until NetherRealm Studios patch it out.

Warner Brother Games have actually made a [tweet](https://twitter.com/WBGamesSupport/status/1433597473113755651) from their official twitter in regards to the issue, which seems to be platform wide according to the previously linked article.  Warner Brother Games linked in their tweet to to [this article](https://dcgamessupport.wbgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001995808-My-game-is-crashing-on-my-PS5-PS4-XB1-or-Xbox-Series-X-S), but I doubt it will get you far, seeing that you already tried what they recommend for Xbox users (included below):

> #### Xbox One and Xbox Series X|S
>
> 1. Press the Xbox button on your controller to open the guide.
> 2. From that menu, select "My Games and Apps" and then select "See all".
> 3. Select the Games tab.
> 4. Highlight your game and press the Menu button on your controller (the button with 3 lines on it) and then select the "Uninstall" option.
> 5. After confirming the uninstall and allowing the process to complete, reinsert the game disc to reinstall the game (if a physical copy of the game) or visit "My Games and Apps" then the "Games tab" and select the game. To download the game again (if a digital copy of the game), press the Menu button and then select "Install"

If you follow the tweets on the linked tweet above, you'll see many other users have tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail.  Thus it seems you will have to wait for a patch.